# Very weird problem with Convert.Double in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a very simple code that works on my PC:

```
    String latitude = "2.3444";
    String longitude = "34.333";

    Double lat = Convert.ToDouble(latitude);
    Double lng = Convert.ToDouble(longitude);
```

In my pc "." is decimal separator.

I uploaded to server. It fails. I looked at Regional Settings, it was "," as decimal separator. I changed it to ".". I stopped my web app and restarted it but it still fails. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

```
using System.Globalization

String latitude = "2.3444";
String longitude = "34.333";

Double lat = Convert.ToDouble(latitude, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Double lng = Convert.ToDouble(longitude, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks it works :) though I still don't understand why since decimal separator is the same.